# Get final score by sum of multiple fields boost

Tags: ruby, solr, sunspot

I want to build a search that prioritizes the amount of field matches instead of one field over another. All the fields would have the same boost value and the final score should be calculated by sum matched fields boost. If the full text matches two fields and each field have boost 1, the final score would be 1 + 1 = 2.

Let's use an example:

`class Event < ApplicationRecord
  searchable do
    text :title
    text :category
    text :artist_name
  end
end`

Suppose I have two events:

**Event 1:** *Name:* "Christmas festival" *Artist name:* "AC/DC"

**Event 2:** *Name:* "New year festival"  *Artist name:* "Queen"

So, if the user searches just "festival", both events are returned with the same score because it matches both event's name.
But, if the user searches "festival AC/DC", I want to return *Event 1* in the first place or just *Event 1* because it matches the event name (festival) and the artist name (AC/DC). While *Event 2* just matches the event name (festival). *Event 1* score should be 2 while *Event 2* score should be 1.

Any suggestion about How can I do that? Is this even possible?

Comment: Excellent, what's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are mixing up scoring and boosting, I think your question should be titled *Compute total score by summing each field score* (regardless of the boosts).

Field scores are computed based on field matches, and they can be applied arbitrary set of additive or multiplicative boosts (functions and/or matching subqueries). But in the end what you want is to compute the global score by summing each field score, not the boosts themselves.

[**DisMax**](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-dismax-query-parser.html) query parser for example precisely allows you to control how the final score is computed using the `tie` (Tie Breaker) parameter :

> The tie parameter specifies a float value (which should be something
>   much less than 1) to use as tiebreaker in DisMax queries.
>
> When a term from the user’s input is tested against multiple fields,
>   more than one field may match. If so, each field will generate a
>   different score based on how common that word is in that field (for
>   each document relative to all other documents). The tie parameter lets
>   you control how much the final score of the query will be influenced
>   by the scores of the lower scoring fields compared to the highest
>   scoring field.
>
> A value of "0.0" - the default - makes the query a pure "disjunction
>   max query": that is, only the maximum scoring subquery contributes to
>   the final score. A value of "1.0" makes the query a pure "disjunction
>   sum query" where it doesn’t matter what the maximum scoring sub query
>   is, because the final score will be the sum of the subquery scores.
>   Typically a low value, such as 0.1, is useful.

In your situation you need a **disjunction sum query** so you might want to set the `tie` to `1.0`.